# Linux: Remove lines starting with [

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I know I can use grep -v '^#' to remove lines starting with #

now I run into issues when I try to do this to remove the [ 
ie. grep -v '^[' or even sed '/^[/ d'

Why is this happening and how can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `grep -v '^\[' InputFile.txt`?

Answer (score 6):

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat brackets 
keep
[remove]
```

Using grep:

```
$ grep -v '^\[' brackets
keep
```

Or:

```
$ grep -v '^[[]' brackets
keep
```

Using sed:

```
$ sed '/^\[/d' brackets 
keep
```

Or:

```
$ sed '/^[[]/d' brackets 
keep
```

#### Why

When a computer command fails to work as expected, it is important to look at the error message.  Consider:

```
$ grep -vE '^[' brackets
grep: Invalid regular expression
```

The error message is reporting that an invalid regular expression was found.  This is because `[` is a regex-active character: `[...]` is used to define a character list.  Thus, if a regex contains an unescaped `[`, it must also contain a matching `]`.  There are two ways to avoid this:

1. Escape it.  If `[` is a regex-active character, then `\[` will generally be treated as a regular (inactive) character.
2. Put it in a character list.  `[[]` is a character list that matches only one character: `[`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. That really helps.